# How to store data in array after a certain line in a file

Tags: python, file

I have a file I am working with this is what it looks like:

```
v
-1.00000000 -1.00000000 -1.00000000             
-1.00000000 1.00000000 -1.00000000            
-1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000          
-1.00000000 1.00000000 -1.00000000             
-1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000             
1.00000000 1.00000000 -1.00000000             
1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000             
1.00000000 -1.00000000 -1.00000000              
1.00000000 1.00000000 -1.00000000               
1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000             
-1.00000000 -1.00000000 -1.00000000            
-1.00000000 -1.00000000 1.00000000   
-1.00000000 -1.00000000 1.00000000      
1.00000000 -1.00000000 1.00000000             
-1.00000000 -1.00000000 -1.00000000          
1.00000000 -1.00000000 -1.00000000         
1.00000000 -1.00000000 1.00000000          
-1.00000000 -1.00000000 -1.00000000       
1.00000000 -1.00000000 -1.00000000         
1.00000000 1.00000000 -1.00000000            
-1.00000000 -1.00000000 -1.00000000          
-1.00000000 1.00000000 -1.00000000           
-1.00000000 1.00000000 -1.00000000        
1.00000000 1.00000000 -1.00000000          
-1.00000000 -1.00000000 1.00000000         
-1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000          
1.00000000 -1.00000000 1.00000000       
-1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000     
1.00000000 -1.00000000 1.00000000         
1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000       
-1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000       
1.00000000 -1.00000000 -1.00000000      
1.00000000 -1.00000000 1.00000000         
1.00000000 1.00000000 -1.00000000           
1.00000000 1.00000000 1.00000000         
-1.00000000 -1.00000000 1.00000000
```

Now I am trying to store all the numbers after "v" into a verts[]. 
This is what I currently have:

```
filepath = os.fsencode(filepath)
file = open(filepath, 'r')
```

Keep in mind the number of verts underneath v will vary. I need to store them all in a verts array. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `verts[]`? What should your output look like? You want an *array*? Or a `list`?

Comment: Try this: pull out text from the file, then find the position by content.find('v'); so number_text = content[position+1:]; then 'split' the number_text like verts=number_text.split(' ') (split by space).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am trying to get an array. **verts[]** will be all the numbers underneath the _v_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `v` is always on the first line you may do something like:

```
with open('verts.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()[1:]

verts = []
for line in lines:
    verts.append([float(p) for p in line.split()])
```

If it is not, you can fetch the lines under it using slicing.

```
with open('verts.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

i = lines.index('v\n')
lines = lines[i + 1:]

verts = []
for line in lines:
    verts.append([float(p) for p in line.split()])
```

Okay, I did came up with something a little more generic in an attempt to parse the file you have (or at least parts of it).

```
def read_data(data, marker='v'):
    marker_index = data.index(marker)

    result = []

    for line in data[marker_index + 1:]:
        if not line:
            break
        result.append([float(n) for n in line.split()])

    return result
```

It reads input from the given marker until an empty line is found. I have tested it with the file you provided to parse the contents of `v` and `vNorms` markers.

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    stripped_data = [l.strip() for l in f]

verts = read_data(stripped_data)

print(len(verts))
print(verts[0])
print(verts[-1])

v_norms = read_data(stripped_data, marker='vNorms')
print(len(v_norms))
print(v_norms[0])
print(v_norms[-1])
```

Output:

```
36
[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0]
[-1.0, -1.0, 1.0]

36
[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[-1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: no it isnt the first line, I just need to be able to access all the information in that block of the file.

Comment: What do you mean by block? Is it the lines underneath the one containing `v`? If that's the case my second example should work.

Comment: I am getting errors for some reason. https://hastebin.com/ofuxukuwey.css There is the file format. All I am trying to do is read all the numbers into seperate items so one Vector 3 as a piece of the array. For example = 1.000000,1.00000,1.000000 is one index in array. I need all of them like that in a verts[]

Comment: You need to read all the numbers listed on the `mesh_info` block or all the numbers from all the lines with three numbers?

Comment: Well I for now I am just trying to make an array that will store all the numbers under the _v_ block named verts[]. Later I will make more arrays such as vertNorms[] that will store all the _vNorms_ block numbers. For now I am just trying to get all the verts. thanks for helping

Comment: Okay, I updated a solution I believe will better suit your needs. Hope it helps.

Comment: so how can I store a variable how you did it. For example if I had a line in the file like this **Number of mesh: (a number)** and I wanted to store that number in a variable

Comment: Well, that case I would search for the line containing the string and parse the number after it. Something like: `line = next(l for l in lines if 'Number of mesh:' in l); num_mesh = int(line.split(':')[1])`. Also note that this will only get the first ocurrence of the number.

Comment: So by using `line = next(l for l in lines if 'Number of mesh:' in l); num_mesh = int(line.split(':')[1])`. This will store the number in the variable num_mesh. So for example if I had **Number of mesh: 1** then num_mesh would equal one? Correct?

Comment: Well, hopefully. =P. It worked on the tests I performed.